# Invalidating layout from within viewDidLayoutSubviews() causes infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

According to multiple SO questions and answers, the right way of updating the layout of UICollectionView is to call `invaliditateLayout()` from within the UICollectionViewController's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. In my case, however, this causes an infinite loop, because after invalidating the layout, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` gets called again etc.

Is it an artifact of some error I made somewhere, and so do I need to fix it? What could be the cause? Or is there any other new recommended way on how to invalidate layout?

Per request, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36884467/5342223) is the SO thread/answer I was referring to.

Per another request, the relevant piece of code follows. I set the size of the collection view with autolayout, and want to show exactly one item at once in the collection view, so I need to dynamically set its size after autolayout finishes. I do that using flow layout delegate.

```
// In ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

// necessary to prevent loop
var shouldLayout = true 
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

    if shouldLayout {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        shouldLayout = false
    }
}

// Later in the file
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // Height and width to fit exactly one item into the CollectionView...
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to invalidate the layout ? What I don't understand is why you want to "relayout" your view just after it finishes to "layout".

Comment: Do you use `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: @sh4rp-eye : Just curious, can you post any links to accepted answer on SO that says call `invaliditateLayout` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` because this will anyway lead to loop wonder how can that be solution in any case !

Comment: can you include links to the questions and answers that suggest to use `invalidateLayout` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari the OP might be talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36884467/3687801)

Comment: @nayem : In a link you posted you are invalidating the collectionView layout in ViewDidLayout of ViewController. In OP's case he is invalidating the layout in its own ViewDidLayoutSubViews :) They aren't same

Comment: Well @SandeepBhandari, nice catch. Then he might be confused with the same method signature without noticing the presence of `ViewController`'s overridden method. Even actually I too didn't notice that prior to your comment 

Comment: @XavierBauquet My CollectionView is in a StackView, and I'd like to have exactly one item per page. So, I invalidate the layout after the autolayout finishes and implement a sizeForItemAt method, which uses collectionView.frame.Width. Is there a better way?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I don't understand. I am overriding the UIViewController method, too.

Comment: @sh4rp-eye : Please post the viewDidLayoutSubviews method to let us understand your problem better

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Done, please see the updated post.