# Reusable UITableViewCell with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

**Code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    registerCells()
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifierForItem(at: indexPath.row), for: indexPath) as? HorizontalCollectionTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    if cellViewModels.count > indexPath.row {
        let viewModel = cellViewModels[indexPath.row]
        cell.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Passing `viewModel` to Cell:**

```
var viewModel: TitleAccessoryButtonCollectionViewModel? {
    didSet {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else {
            return
        }
        titleLabel.text = viewModel.title
        if let buttonTitle = viewModel.accessoryButtonModel?.title {
            setAccessoryButtonTitle(buttonTitle)
        }else{
            accessoryButton.hideTitleLabel()
        }

        if let buttonImage = viewModel.accessoryButtonModel?.image {
            accessoryButton.buttonImageView.image = buttonImage
        }
        else {
            accessoryButton.hideImageView()
        }

        sectionContentImage.image = viewModel.sectionContentImage
        titleLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = viewModel.titleLabelLeadingSpacing
        accessoryButton.isHidden = viewModel.hideAccessoryButton
        sectionContentView.isHidden = viewModel.hidePremiumContentView
        let collectionViewModel = viewModel.collectionViewModel
        collectionViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(collectionViewModel.height)
        collectionViewModel.setup(collectionView: collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = collectionViewModel.delegate
        collectionView.dataSource = collectionViewModel.dataSource
        collectionView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

**Description:**

I have six `UITableViewCell` mostly, and they are reusable.

In every `UITableViewCell` is `UICollectionView`.

Five `UICollectionView's` use normal `UICollectionViewFlowLayout's`, but one needs a custom subclass.

The problem is that when `UITableViewCell` with custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is hiding and new UITableViewCell is showing and cell with this custom flow layout is reused and `UICollectionView` already have `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but is bad.

Is any nice way to clear this layout or prevent this situation?

Maybe something with `prepareForReuse()`?

I add that `UICollectionView` is outlet in `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayouts means items in 2 rows close to each other. Normal is just horizontal collection with good spacing and this custom is reused in row where should be normal flow layout. just it

Answer (score 0):

This excellent article helped me a lot to get UICollectionViews in UITableviewCells up and running: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

To update the layout you can call

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

See also:
[Swift: How to refresh UICollectionView layout after rotation of the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884376/swift-how-to-refresh-uicollectionview-layout-after-rotation-of-the-device/42174492)

Comment: I tried invalidateLayout() in PrepareForReuse but it does not work for me

Comment: Where do you set the different layouts to the collectionview? You need to call invalidateLayout() after that. PrepareForReuse is probably too early as it's called before cellForRow so the collectionView does not know anything about the new layout. Try calling invalidateLayout() in the viewModel didSet of your cell.

Comment: new layout is created in collectionViewModel.setup(collectionView: collectionView) in didSet.

Comment: Optional(<CollectionViewHorizontalHuggingLayout: 0x7fb8a5c05380>) DLA -> Backstage COLLECTIONVIEW -> 0x00007fb8a1174400 TABLEVIEW -> 0x00007fb8a117e200

Optional(<CollectionViewHorizontalHuggingLayout: 0x7fb8a5c05380>) DLA -> Recommendations COLLECTIONVIEW -> 0x00007fb8a1174400 TABLEVIEW -> 0x00007fb8a117e200

I tried at top of didSet but nothing. You can see that cell from Backstage is reuse for Recommendation and the FlowLayout is the same but should not be...

Comment: Try the end of didSet or within collectionViewModel.setup(collectionView: collectionView) after the new layout is set to the collectionView

Comment: Did it work? If so, please mark answer as correct. Thx.